# G=(16, 13) notation

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I hope this is an easy question but no so easy to be wiped out. I have asked few physical people (Profs) here in our department, and nobody has a clue. I'm reading this paper:

[The locus of curves with prescribed automorphism group](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AG/0205314)

and it uses following notation to represent a group:

G = (16, 13)

This is at the beginning of page 11. Shaska uses this notation in his other papers but I couldn't find an explanation for the kind of groups he's talking about. Could you please tell me exactly what's the meaning of this bracket notation? It could be a GAP thing but unfortunately I'm not a GAP person.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems to refer to the number of the finite group in the GAP database. The first number is the order of the group and the second is the GAP-specific number of that particular group among all groups of that order. E.g. in MAGMA, this group is created with the command SmallGroup(16,13).

Comment: I see. So it's the 13th group of order 16. Is GAP using a particular way to order all groups of order n?

Comment: Not a GAP person, *yet*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Alex Bartel is correct that the notation $(16,13)$ refers to SmallGroup(16,13), then here are generators for your group:
$$
\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -i & 0 \\
 0 & i
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)\right\}$$

It is extremely convenient to calculate such representations in GAP.  Here is the code that generated this representation:

IrreducibleRepresentations(SmallGroup(16,13))[10];

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to check GAP/MAGMA to see if I get the same thing.

Comment: I think I got my answer but it rises the new question that what's the logic behind the ordering in small group database. I think I should be able to find my answer if I dig into GAP documents.

Comment: I don't think the ordering is completely canonical, but the outer-most criterion for ordering (for p-groups) is the size of the minimum generating set. So for a p-group, the cyclic group always comes first, then all the subgroups generated by 2 elements, then all the subgroups generated by 3 elements, and so on, and the elementary abelian group comes last.

Comment: Also, you can get more information on groups of order 16 here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16